# Unable to access rclone mount in Powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, sftp, rclone

I've mounted my server using [SFTP](https://rclone.org/sftp/) (as F: drive) on Windows 10, but Powershell can't access the drive and as a result I must open all files via Windows Explorer which loads extremely slowly.

When running `cd F:\`:

```
cd : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'F' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd F:\
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (F:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: [rclone] tag didn't exist — I wonder how come.

Comment: Does F display when you run `Get-PSDrive F`?

Comment: @michaelg: A similar error: `Get-PSDrive : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'F' does not exist.`